# Scrapy : getting only td elements with ALIGN=RIGHT

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to scrape data from this website: http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxevent.html

I need to seperate dates from counts of UFO sightings, yes exciting!

Here is an example of what I'm scraping

`<TR VALIGN=TOP>
<TD><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:11pt FACE="Calibri" COLOR=#000000><A HREF= ndxe201303.html>03/2013</A></TD>
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT><FONT style=FONT-SIZE:11pt FACE="Calibri" COLOR=#000000>108</TD>`

So in this example date = 03/2013, count = 108

Now the dates are not a problem since I can just do

```
hxs.select('//tbody//td//font//a//text()').extract()
```

To get the text within "a" tag.

But is there a way to get text from td element that has the style ALIGN=RIGHT.
I have looked at the docs and selectors but I'm confused

```
hxs.select('//tbody[contains(td, "ALIGN")]').extract()
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selects text from all `<td>` with the *attribute* `ALIGN="RIGHT"`:

```
hxs.select('//tbody//td[@ALIGN="RIGHT"]//text()').extract()
```

Comment: For some strange reason I need two '/', so your line works if I write it like this: hxs.select('//tbody//td[contains(@align, "RIGHT")]//text()').extract() --thank you very much :D

Comment: `/text()` matches text that follows immediately after the closing tag `</td>`. `//text()` matches all text of all subtags within `<td>..</td>`.